# Reconstruct dataframe with dates as date intervals in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset basically looks like that, giving which campaigns are active for each household with given start and end dates of respective campaigns:

```
  campaign_id household_id campaign_type start_date end_date     
1 26          1            Type B        2016-12-28 2017-02-19
2 8           1            Type A        2017-05-08 2017-06-25
3 12          1            Type B        2017-07-12 2017-08-13
4 13          1            Type A        2017-08-08 2017-09-24
5 18          1            Type A        2017-10-30 2017-12-24
6 20          1            Type C        2017-11-27 2018-02-05
7 22          1            Type B        2017-12-06 2018-01-07
8 23          1            Type B        2017-12-28 2018-02-04
```

And I create a new dataframe with given structure, which will show which campaigns are active for given household in a given time (having all the campaign numbers as columns, i have omitted the rest while putting here):

```
   household_id       date campaign1 campaign2 campaign3 campaign4
1             1 2016-11-14        NA        NA        NA        NA
2             1 2016-12-06        NA        NA        NA        NA
3             1 2016-12-28        NA        NA        NA        NA
4             1 2017-02-08        NA        NA        NA        NA
5             1 2017-03-03        NA        NA        NA        NA
6             1 2017-03-08        NA        NA        NA        NA
7             1 2017-03-13        NA        NA        NA        NA
8             1 2017-03-29        NA        NA        NA        NA
9             1 2017-04-03        NA        NA        NA        NA
10            1 2017-04-19        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

What I want to do is assigning the active promotions in the given dates as rows in the second dataframe. For example if household_id 1 is having campaign 2 running in 2016-11-14 but no other campaigns, then it will look like this:

```
   household_id       date campaign1 campaign2 campaign3 campaign4
1             1 2016-11-14         0         1         0         0
```

How can i manage this construction, should I use for loops in the initial dataframe and assign to second one in each loop, or there is a better and faster way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @jay.sf I was thinking of using by() function like this: by(dataFrame1, 1:nrow(dataFrame1), function(row)) with a function checking which column no put 0s and 1s in the second dataframe (maybe with elseifs) and writing data accordingly, but it looked real tedious and slow in theory.

Comment: @AtakanCavuslu - maybe it would be helpful if you provided additional example data with the `household_id` and campaign number - where is this data coming from? In your example, you have campaign 2 only - why? If you can provide a basic example for the source of data (what you're starting with), and indicate what your final result should look like (what you want to end up with), additional suggestions can be made?